# How to send text and binary over socket in single message in C?

Tags: c, sockets

I know how to send text message over the socket in C and I know how to send binary data (image file) over the socket.

How to create a single message including text part and then binary data? For example:

```
"messageId: 12, messageLength: 34

{image binary data}"
```

Comment: You already know how to send text, and how to send binary, so what is stopping you from combining them? Send the text first, then send the binary after. TCP has no concept of messages, so it doesn't care how many sends you make. Your *protocol* dictates what a *message* contains. Have a look at the HTTP protocol, for example. It uses mixed text+binary messages.

Comment: @RemyLebeau – HTTP can send text and image but you send image in base64 (which is +33% to message size).

Comment: If you need HTTP, say so in the title. You can send a lot of stuff over a socket that would break the HTTP protocol.

Comment: @n.m. I need pure TCP socket

Comment: Why bring up HTTP then? BTW HTTP doesn't make you use base64 to send images.

Comment: @n.m. there is nothing about HTTP in the title it's TCP. I wrote about HTTP when answering to RemyLebeau.

Comment: I mentioned HTTP just as an *example* of a protocol that can send text and binary in a single message.

Comment: Pick a protocol that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP doesn't know what a "text" or a "message" are. It deals with streams of bytes. If you have an array of bytes, you can send it over TCP. If you have more than one array, you can send them over TCP one by one, and the result will be indistinguishable from concatenating all these arrays to one and sending them as one big chunk of bytes.

Sending bytes --- any bytes --- over TCP is not a problem. The problem is extracting meaningful parts ("messages") from a byte stream. It has nothing to do with TCP, and everything to do with how you define "message" in terms of your stream *content* --- that is, your *protocol*.

You can define your protocol by saying "a message is a line, ending with the newline character", and this is fine for sending text messages that do not have an embedded newline. It will not work for binary messages, because a binary blob is likely to have an embedded newline character.

You can define a message by saying "a message is a 4-byte quantity interpreted as a network-order unsigned integer, followed by that many bytes of the payload". This is fine for both text and binary messages, but is slightly inconvenient for text because you have to compute and send the length of every string.

You can say "my stream contains strictly alternating text and binary messages, text being terminated by a newline and binary being preceded by its length", and this will work too, although you cannot send two text or two binary messages in a row.

You can say "my stream contains exactly two messages, a text ending with a newline, and then a binary". No length is sent explicitly, the end of the stream is the end of the binary message.

See, it's all in your protocol. TCP doesn't care. All it knows is bytes.

Comment: I missed reading from you. +1

Comment: Just about perfect:)

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: memcpy and a special separator char between text header and binary data. The separator can easily be a an end of line char (`\n`)

```
char* CreateMessage(int messageId, size_t messageLength, char* binaryData, /*out*/ size_t* total)
{
    char szHeader[100] = {0};
    size_t headerLen = 0;

    sprintf(szHeader, "messageId: %d, messageLength: %d\n", messageId, messageLength);

    headerLen = strlen(szHeader);

    total = headerLen + messageLength;

    char* data = malloc(total);
    memcpy(data, header, headerLen);
    memcpy(data+headerLen, binaryData, messageLength);

    return data;
}
```

And then when you want to send some data:

```
size_t total = 0;
char* message = CreateMessage(12, 34, binaryData, &total);
send(s, message, total, 0);
free(message);
```

Alternatively, if you are using TCP, there's no reason why you can't use two send calls. One for the header (with the '\n' char) and another for the binary data. The receiver has to handle messages getting segmented and fragmented anyway.

Comment: There is no character that can securely differentiate between 'text' and 'binary data'.  'text' is a subset of 'binary data'.

Comment: @MartinJames - Correct. The point I'm making is that he can easily combine his "text" header with his "binary" data if uses an appropriate delimiter to mark the end of the text line.